How to Bootstrap a daily compounding future in QuantLib
Hi I am currently tying to bootstrap the F-TIIE curve for mexican swaps
In the short term it uses the F-TIIE Futures.
These F-TIIE futures are 1 month futures that start on the first day of the month regardless of holidays. They are compounded daily throughout the term with 1 day forward rates (funding rates).
I am currently trying to bootstrap it using ql.OvernightIndexFutureRateHelper but it is not right.
Here is the methodology for settlement calculation
